# How to display cropped part of an image while maintaining aspect ratio?

Tags: jquery, thumbnails, crop

I am using the imgareaSelect jquery plugin to provide UI to crop an image. I want the user to be able to select an arbitrary part of an image, i.e., aspect ratio is not previously fixed. Moreover the size of the source picture is also not known, but the preview area has a fixed maximum width. In the example shown on the website [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/), the aspect ratio is fixed to 1:1. How to do this for an arbitrary aspect ratio? The crop preview should have a height proportional to the selection, but a fixed width of 100px.